# pageshow時にコラプシブルパネルを開きたい

Tags: monaca, jquery-mobile

Monacaで開発しています。
`pageinit`時の`$("#id").data("collapsed",false)`は画面に反映されますが、
`pageshow`時の`$("#id").data("collapsed",false)`は画面に反映されていないように見えます。
原因と対処方法を教えていただきたいです。

例えば`pageshow`時の`$("#id").data("collapsed",false)`の上下を
`console.log($("#id").data("collapsed"))`で挟むと、

```
true
false
```

とログに出るため確かにデータは変わっているのですが、画面のコラプシブルパネルは閉じたままです。
`pageinit`時は反映されるのに、`pageshow`時は反映されない原因が推測できません。
何かリロードのような作業が必要になるのでしょうか。

`pageshow`の部分を`pagebeforeshow`に変更しても結果は変わりませんでした。
`data-collapsed`を書き換えるAPIを

```
$("#id").attr("data-collapsed",false);
```

としても、やはり`pageinit`では反映されますが、`pageshow`では反映されませんでした。

**■JavaScript**

```js
    $(document).on("pageinit","#page1",function(){
        $("#collap1").data("collapsed",true);
        $("#collap2").data("collapsed",false);    //これは動く。
            //＝collap2が開いた状態になる。
            //※特にcollap2が開いている必要は無いが検証のためfalseにした。
        $("#collap3").data("collapsed",true);

        $(document).on("pageshow","#page2",function(){
            //一旦全部閉じる
            $("#collap1").data("collapsed",true);
            $("#collap2").data("collapsed",true);
            $("#collap3").data("collapsed",true);
            //指定のコラプシブルパネルだけ開く。　※反映されない
            $("#collap1").data("collapsed",false);
            //バインドされているのか確認
            console.log("動いてます");    //これはログに表示されるから動いてはいるようだ。
        });
    });
```

**■HTML**

```
<div data-role="page" id="page1">
    <div data-role="content">
        <a href="#page2>Link1</a>
    </div>
</div
<div data-role="page" id="page2">
    <div data-role="ui-content">
        <div data-role="collapsible-set">
            <div data-role="collapsible" data-collapsed="true" id="collap1">
                <h3>Title1</h3>
                <ul data-role="listview">
                    <li><a href="#page1">content1</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#page1">content2</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#page1">content3</a></li>
                </ul>
            </div>
            <div data-role="collapsible" data-collapsed="true" id="collap2">
                <h3>Title2</h3>
                <ul data-role="listview">
                    <li><a href="#page1">content4</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#page1">content5</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#page1">content6</a></li>
                </ul>
            </div>
            <div data-role="collapsible" data-collapsed="true" id="collap3">
                <h3>Title3</h3>
                <ul data-role="listview">
                    <li><a href="#page1">content7</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#page1">content8</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#page1">content9</a></li>
                </ul>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

解決策を見つけました。expandで開くことができました。
http://demos.jquerymobile.com/1.2.0/docs/content/content-collapsible-methods.html